# missing attribute error Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, scope

I cant seem to get the result of a scope to display in my view as i get this error message.I am trying to get all of the memberships amounts for the day added up and displayed as a total

```
missing attribute: membership_id
```

My Models and scope

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :membership
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :membership

 attr_accessible :membership_id, :forename, :middlename, :surname, :house_no, :house_name, :street, :town, :postcode, :home_tel, :mobile_tel, :work_tel, :email, :start_date, :expiry_date

scope :new_memberships_cash_today, ->() {
joins(:membership).where(:start_date => Date.today).select('ROUND(SUM(memberships.cost), 2)')
}
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :members, :dependent => :destroy
attr_accessible :membership_type, :cost 
end
```

And then my view

```
columns do

  #Total amount in £ for New Memberships today
   column do
    panel "Cash Today", :class => 'NewAmountMemberships' do
     table_for Member.new_memberships_cash_today  do 
      column 'Total cash' do |c|
       c.membership.map { |e| [e.cost, e.id] }
      end 
     end     
    end
   end
  end
```

After some reading it would seem that there may be an issue with my select call in the scope, as i need to specify all of the models attributes to make a successful call with Active Record?

As i am performing a sum within the select i am unsure how to add more attributes, if this is even the case

Any help appreciated

i have run the scope in the the console and this is what is returned

```
Member Load (0.1ms)  SELECT ROUND(SUM(memberships.cost), 2) FROM `members` INNER JOIN `memberships` ON `memberships`.`id` = `members`.`membership_id` WHERE `members`.`start_date` = '2013-12-13'
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Member id: nil>]>
```

Comment: Your scope returns a single object and the only thing you can access from that object is the sum. I can see you trying to access membership on the object from the scope. Since it doesn't have membership_id, you are getting the error

Comment: thanks, so any idea on how to tweak my scope to still return the sum of the column cost in membership model ?

Comment: `attr_accessible :membership_id` is very bad practice! No associated ids should be accessible via params. This will allow a savvy user to associate a member with an arbitrary membership.

Comment: so what if i changed that to membership_attributes instead or would that still give access, i thought we had to include this so associated model attributes can be accessed?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do this in a scope, but in a helper method.  That way you can grab the associated records and just call your method to return the total.

Something along the lines of this:

```
def membership_sum(memberships = [])
  sum = 0
  memberships.each { |membership| sum += membership.cost }
  sum.round
end
```

Now, store the associated records in a @memberships variable (from within your controller) and then, in your view, use `<%= membership_sum(@memberships) %>`

Comment: ok, would really appreciate an example if you have time..something that i can look at and learn off, thanks

Comment: Just a minor improvement: `memberships.map(&:cost).sum.round`

Comment: I intentionally kept it simple for clarity, but I like your answer @DamienRoche

Comment: i cant get this to work im afraid. I have put the method in my member model, but how is this accessing my memberships model attributes? and i cant see how i would use this in my view as stated in the question? any further help appreciated

Comment: Yea, my apologies, the original post said model method, but I meant a helper method.  You'll want to put it in your application_helper.rb (or a view specific helper file, member_helper.rb in your case)

Comment: ok its now in the application_helper..the only thing i am struggling with now is passing the member object through the helper in the view..I have this      table_for Member.membership_sum do 
          column 'Total cash' do |c|
           membership_sum(c)
          end

Comment: No, please see the answer, I show you how to use it in your view.  Store the records you want to total in @memberships (in your controller) and then call the helper as I've outlined.  I just updated the answer to clarify this.

Comment: ah right, sorry if this is a stupid question then but im using active admin so i need to get it in that controller?

Comment: I'm not familiar with active admin, but yes you would want to define @memberships in whichever controller is handling your view.  Also, put the helper method in application_helper.rb (for simplicity, as it will then be available site-wide)